# Neo4j Is it possible to set a property on a relationship that is the result of the count funtion

Tags: neo4j

Using the example movie database, I'm trying to build a new relationship between the directors and actors such that there is a "relationship strength" property on the relationship that is the number of time the director has directed the actor.

The following makes the connection:

```
MATCH (t)-[a]->(m)<-[d]-dir 
WHERE t.name CONTAINS "Tom H" AND type(a) CONTAINS "ACT" AND type(d) CONTAINS "DIR" 
MERGE (dir)-[r:DIRECTED]->t  
RETURN t, dir
```

and the relationship strength can be found with

```
MATCH (t)-[a]->(m)<-[d]-dir 
WHERE t.name CONTAINS "Tom H" AND type(a) CONTAINS "ACT" AND type(d) CONTAINS "DIR"  
RETURN dir.name, COLLECT(m.title) AS movies, count(m) AS RelationshipStrength
```

I want to effectively set a property on DIRECTED to be relationshipStrength.

Is this possible? or must count on be used following a RETURN statement while sets and merges must be before the RETURN statement?

Answer (score 0):

Sure no problem:

```
MATCH (t)-[a]->(m)<-[d]-dir 
WHERE t.name CONTAINS "Tom H" AND type(a) CONTAINS "ACT" AND type(d) CONTAINS "DIR"  
WITH dir, t, COLLECT(m.title) AS movies, count(m) AS RelationshipStrength
MERGE (dir)-[r:DIRECTED]->(t) ON CREATE SET r.strength = RelationshipStrength
RETURN dir.name, t.name, movies, RelationshipStrength
```

You probably know that you can use the rel-types like `:ACTED_IN` directly in the pattern? And that you'd use parameters in a real-world query.

I would also use a different relationship-type to discern it from the other `:DIRECTED` relationship.